# How to re-triggeer the animationTransform through js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Here I am using SMIL animations for firefox. My problem is animation is triggering at the time of page loading. I need to start the animation dynamically through JS. I think the problem is coming through the `begin` attribute. so, How can I do that thing?. Below I attached my code for your reference.

Thanks!

**HTML**

```html
<svg width="710px" height="231px" viewBox="0 0 710 231">
<!-- Generator: Sketch 53.2 (72643) - https://sketchapp.com  -->
<title>Chart_IncreaseInAttacks</title>
<desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
<defs>
  <clipPath id="clip-path-increaseinattacks" class="graph-clipath active">
     <path x="150" y="0" height="300" transform= translate(-505,0) width="505"
      d="M150,75 L643,75 C649.627417,75 655,80.372583 655,87 L655,87 C655,93.627417 649.627417,99 643,99 L150,99 L150,75 Z"
      id="Rectangle-Copy-15" fill="#0F54AF" fill-rule="nonzero">
       <animateTransform 
       attributeType="XML" 
        attributeName="transform" 
        type="translate"
        values="-505,0; 0,0" 
        begin="0s"
        calcMode="spline"
        keySplines= ".4,0,.78,.69"
        dur="0.3s" 
        fill="freeze"/>
    </path>
     <path x="150" y="0" height="300" transform = translate(-505,0) width="505"
      d="M150,117 L499,117 C505.627417,117 511,122.372583 511,129 L511,129 C511,135.627417 505.627417,141 499,141 L150,141 L150,117 Z"
      id="Rectangle-Copy-18" fill="#009FDB" fill-rule="nonzero">
       <animateTransform 
       attributeType="XML" 
        attributeName="transform" 
        type="translate"
        values="-505,0; 0,0" 
        begin="0.3s"
        calcMode="spline"
        keySplines= ".4,0,.78,.69" 
        dur="0.3s" 
        fill="freeze"/>
    </path>
     <path x="150" y="0" height="300" transform= translate(-505,0) width="505"
      d="M150,159 L239,159 C245.627417,159 251,164.372583 251,171 L251,171 C251,177.627417 245.627417,183 239,183 L150,183 L150,159 Z"
      id="Rectangle-Copy-19" fill="#30D1FF" fill-rule="nonzero">
       <animateTransform 
       attributeType="XML" 
        attributeName="transform" 
        type="translate"
        values="-505,0; 0,0" 
        begin="0.6s"
        calcMode="spline"
        keySplines= ".4,0,.78,.69"
        dur="0.3s" 
        fill="freeze"/>
    </path>
 </clipPath>
</defs>
 <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
  <g id="ATT-CS-Report02_SecurityRiskLandscape" transform="translate(-245.000000, -440.000000)">
  <g id="Chart_IncreaseInAttacks" transform="translate(245.000000, 440.000000)">
  <rect id="Rectangle-Copy-14" fill="#F6F6F6" fill-rule="nonzero" x="0" y="0" width="710" height="231"></rect>
  <text id="Increase-in-attacks" font-size="15" font-weight="bold" line-spacing="22" fill="#009FDB">
  <tspan x="42" y="40">Increase in attacks in 2018</tspan>
  </text>
  <text id="Ransomware-attacks" font-size="11" font-weight="normal" line-spacing="14" fill="#191919">
  <tspan x="68.462" y="83">Ransomware </tspan>
  <tspan x="96.765" y="97">attacks</tspan>
  </text>
  <text id="Spear-phishing-attac" font-size="11" font-weight="normal" line-spacing="14" fill="#191919">
  <tspan x="58.199" y="167">Spear-phishing</tspan>
  <tspan x="96.765" y="181">attacks</tspan>
  </text>
  <text id="Spoofing/BEC-attacks" font-size="11" font-weight="normal" line-spacing="14" fill="#191919">
  <tspan x="83.301" y="125">Spoofing/</tspan>
  <tspan x="74.27" y="139">BEC attacks</tspan>
  </text>
  
   
    
    <path clip-path="url(#clip-path-increaseinattacks)" id="kk"
  d="M150,75 L643,75 C649.627417,75 655,80.372583 655,87 L655,87 C655,93.627417 649.627417,99 643,99 L150,99 L150,75 Z"
  id="Rectangle-Copy-15" fill="#0F54AF" fill-rule="nonzero"> </path>
  <path clip-path="url(#clip-path-increaseinattacks)"
  d="M150,117 L499,117 C505.627417,117 511,122.372583 511,129 L511,129 C511,135.627417 505.627417,141 499,141 L150,141 L150,117 Z"
  id="Rectangle-Copy-18" fill="#009FDB" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
  <path clip-path="url(#clip-path-increaseinattacks)"
   d="M150,159 L239,159 C245.627417,159 251,164.372583 251,171 L251,171 C251,177.627417 245.627417,183 239,183 L150,183 L150,159 Z"
   id="Rectangle-Copy-19" fill="#30D1FF" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
    
    
    
    
   <path d="M150.5,68.5 L150.5,190" id="Line-3-Copy" stroke="#191919" stroke-linecap="square" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
   <text id="350%" font-size="12" font-weight="bold" line-spacing="16" fill="#FFFFFF">
   <tspan x="159" y="90">350%</tspan>
   </text>
   <text id="250%" font-size="12" font-weight="bold" line-spacing="16" fill="#FFFFFF">
    <tspan x="159" y="132">250%</tspan>
   </text>
   <text id="70%" font-size="12" font-weight="bold" line-spacing="16" fill="#FFFFFF">
   <tspan x="159" y="174">70%</tspan>
   </text>
</g>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: @RobertLongson, the code is working fine. I want to re-trigger the same animation. while the user scrolls the page. My question is how to retrigger this animation.

Comment: Yup. my mistake. sorry, updating the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call beginElement to trigger an animation.

I've chained the other animations to the first one to start so they all still work.

```html
<button onclick="document.getElementById('t1').beginElement()">trigger</button>
<svg width="710px" height="231px" viewBox="0 0 710 231">
<!-- Generator: Sketch 53.2 (72643) - https://sketchapp.com  -->
<title>Chart_IncreaseInAttacks</title>
<desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
<defs>
  <clipPath id="clip-path-increaseinattacks" class="graph-clipath active">
     <path x="150" y="0" height="300" transform= translate(-505,0) width="505"
      d="M150,75 L643,75 C649.627417,75 655,80.372583 655,87 L655,87 C655,93.627417 649.627417,99 643,99 L150,99 L150,75 Z"
      id="Rectangle-Copy-15" fill="#0F54AF" fill-rule="nonzero">
       <animateTransform 
       id="t1"
        attributeName="transform" 
        type="translate"
        values="-505,0; 0,0" 
        begin="indefinite"
        calcMode="spline"
        keySplines= ".4,0,.78,.69"
        dur="0.3s" 
        fill="freeze"/>
    </path>
     <path x="150" y="0" height="300" transform = translate(-505,0) width="505"
      d="M150,117 L499,117 C505.627417,117 511,122.372583 511,129 L511,129 C511,135.627417 505.627417,141 499,141 L150,141 L150,117 Z"
      id="Rectangle-Copy-18" fill="#009FDB" fill-rule="nonzero">
       <animateTransform 
        id="t2"
        attributeName="transform" 
        type="translate"
        values="-505,0; 0,0" 
        begin="t1.end"
        calcMode="spline"
        keySplines= ".4,0,.78,.69" 
        dur="0.3s" 
        fill="freeze"/>
    </path>
     <path x="150" y="0" height="300" transform= translate(-505,0) width="505"
      d="M150,159 L239,159 C245.627417,159 251,164.372583 251,171 L251,171 C251,177.627417 245.627417,183 239,183 L150,183 L150,159 Z"
      id="Rectangle-Copy-19" fill="#30D1FF" fill-rule="nonzero">
       <animateTransform 
       attributeName="transform" 
        type="translate"
        values="-505,0; 0,0" 
        begin="t2.end"
        calcMode="spline"
        keySplines= ".4,0,.78,.69"
        dur="0.3s" 
        fill="freeze"/>
    </path>
 </clipPath>
</defs>
 <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
  <g id="ATT-CS-Report02_SecurityRiskLandscape" transform="translate(-245.000000, -440.000000)">
  <g id="Chart_IncreaseInAttacks" transform="translate(245.000000, 440.000000)">
  <rect id="Rectangle-Copy-14" fill="#F6F6F6" fill-rule="nonzero" x="0" y="0" width="710" height="231"></rect>
  <text id="Increase-in-attacks" font-size="15" font-weight="bold" line-spacing="22" fill="#009FDB">
  <tspan x="42" y="40">Increase in attacks in 2018</tspan>
  </text>
  <text id="Ransomware-attacks" font-size="11" font-weight="normal" line-spacing="14" fill="#191919">
  <tspan x="68.462" y="83">Ransomware </tspan>
  <tspan x="96.765" y="97">attacks</tspan>
  </text>
  <text id="Spear-phishing-attac" font-size="11" font-weight="normal" line-spacing="14" fill="#191919">
  <tspan x="58.199" y="167">Spear-phishing</tspan>
  <tspan x="96.765" y="181">attacks</tspan>
  </text>
  <text id="Spoofing/BEC-attacks" font-size="11" font-weight="normal" line-spacing="14" fill="#191919">
  <tspan x="83.301" y="125">Spoofing/</tspan>
  <tspan x="74.27" y="139">BEC attacks</tspan>
  </text>
  
   
    
    <path clip-path="url(#clip-path-increaseinattacks)" id="kk"
  d="M150,75 L643,75 C649.627417,75 655,80.372583 655,87 L655,87 C655,93.627417 649.627417,99 643,99 L150,99 L150,75 Z"
  id="Rectangle-Copy-15" fill="#0F54AF" fill-rule="nonzero"> </path>
  <path clip-path="url(#clip-path-increaseinattacks)"
  d="M150,117 L499,117 C505.627417,117 511,122.372583 511,129 L511,129 C511,135.627417 505.627417,141 499,141 L150,141 L150,117 Z"
  id="Rectangle-Copy-18" fill="#009FDB" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
  <path clip-path="url(#clip-path-increaseinattacks)"
   d="M150,159 L239,159 C245.627417,159 251,164.372583 251,171 L251,171 C251,177.627417 245.627417,183 239,183 L150,183 L150,159 Z"
   id="Rectangle-Copy-19" fill="#30D1FF" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
    
    
    
    
   <path d="M150.5,68.5 L150.5,190" id="Line-3-Copy" stroke="#191919" stroke-linecap="square" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
   <text id="350%" font-size="12" font-weight="bold" line-spacing="16" fill="#FFFFFF">
   <tspan x="159" y="90">350%</tspan>
   </text>
   <text id="250%" font-size="12" font-weight="bold" line-spacing="16" fill="#FFFFFF">
    <tspan x="159" y="132">250%</tspan>
   </text>
   <text id="70%" font-size="12" font-weight="bold" line-spacing="16" fill="#FFFFFF">
   <tspan x="159" y="174">70%</tspan>
   </text>
</g>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to retrigger the animation you have to use the `beginElement()` method. In the code I've made some changes:

The first `animateTransform` has an `id = "a"`
The second `animateTransform` has an `id = "b"` and begins when the a animation ends: `begin="a.end"`
The 3-rd `animateTransform` begins when the b animation ends: `begin="b.end"`

I hope it helps.

```js
svg.addEventListener("click",()=>{
  a.beginElement()
})
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="710px" height="231px" viewBox="0 0 710 231">
<!-- Generator: Sketch 53.2 (72643) - https://sketchapp.com  -->
<title>Chart_IncreaseInAttacks</title>
<desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
<defs>
  <clipPath id="clip-path-increaseinattacks" class="graph-clipath active">
     <path x="150" y="0" height="300" transform= translate(-505,0) width="505"
      d="M150,75 L643,75 C649.627417,75 655,80.372583 655,87 L655,87 C655,93.627417 649.627417,99 643,99 L150,99 L150,75 Z"
      id="Rectangle-Copy-15" fill="#0F54AF" fill-rule="nonzero">
       <animateTransform 
        id="a"
       attributeType="XML" 
        attributeName="transform" 
        type="translate"
        values="-505,0; 0,0" 
        begin="0s;"
        calcMode="spline"
        keySplines= ".4,0,.78,.69"
        dur="0.3s" 
        fill="freeze"/>
    </path>
     <path x="150" y="0" height="300" transform = translate(-505,0) width="505"
      d="M150,117 L499,117 C505.627417,117 511,122.372583 511,129 L511,129 C511,135.627417 505.627417,141 499,141 L150,141 L150,117 Z"
      id="Rectangle-Copy-18" fill="#009FDB" fill-rule="nonzero">
       <animateTransform 
        id="b"
       attributeType="XML" 
        attributeName="transform" 
        type="translate"
        values="-505,0; 0,0" 
        begin="a.end"
        calcMode="spline"
        keySplines= ".4,0,.78,.69" 
        dur="0.3s" 
        fill="freeze"/>
    </path>
     <path x="150" y="0" height="300" transform= translate(-505,0) width="505"
      d="M150,159 L239,159 C245.627417,159 251,164.372583 251,171 L251,171 C251,177.627417 245.627417,183 239,183 L150,183 L150,159 Z"
      id="Rectangle-Copy-19" fill="#30D1FF" fill-rule="nonzero">
       <animateTransform 
       attributeType="XML" 
        attributeName="transform" 
        type="translate"
        values="-505,0; 0,0" 
        begin="b.end"
        calcMode="spline"
        keySplines= ".4,0,.78,.69"
        dur="0.3s" 
        fill="freeze"/>
    </path>
 </clipPath>
</defs>
 <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
  <g id="ATT-CS-Report02_SecurityRiskLandscape" transform="translate(-245.000000, -440.000000)">
  <g id="Chart_IncreaseInAttacks" transform="translate(245.000000, 440.000000)">
  <rect id="Rectangle-Copy-14" fill="#F6F6F6" fill-rule="nonzero" x="0" y="0" width="710" height="231"></rect>
  <text id="Increase-in-attacks" font-size="15" font-weight="bold" line-spacing="22" fill="#009FDB">
  <tspan x="42" y="40">Increase in attacks in 2018</tspan>
  </text>
  <text id="Ransomware-attacks" font-size="11" font-weight="normal" line-spacing="14" fill="#191919">
  <tspan x="68.462" y="83">Ransomware </tspan>
  <tspan x="96.765" y="97">attacks</tspan>
  </text>
  <text id="Spear-phishing-attac" font-size="11" font-weight="normal" line-spacing="14" fill="#191919">
  <tspan x="58.199" y="167">Spear-phishing</tspan>
  <tspan x="96.765" y="181">attacks</tspan>
  </text>
  <text id="Spoofing/BEC-attacks" font-size="11" font-weight="normal" line-spacing="14" fill="#191919">
  <tspan x="83.301" y="125">Spoofing/</tspan>
  <tspan x="74.27" y="139">BEC attacks</tspan>
  </text>
  
   
    
    <path clip-path="url(#clip-path-increaseinattacks)" 
  d="M150,75 L643,75 C649.627417,75 655,80.372583 655,87 L655,87 C655,93.627417 649.627417,99 643,99 L150,99 L150,75 Z"
  id="Rectangle-Copy-15" fill="#0F54AF" fill-rule="nonzero"> </path>
  <path clip-path="url(#clip-path-increaseinattacks)"
  d="M150,117 L499,117 C505.627417,117 511,122.372583 511,129 L511,129 C511,135.627417 505.627417,141 499,141 L150,141 L150,117 Z"
  id="Rectangle-Copy-18" fill="#009FDB" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
  <path clip-path="url(#clip-path-increaseinattacks)"
   d="M150,159 L239,159 C245.627417,159 251,164.372583 251,171 L251,171 C251,177.627417 245.627417,183 239,183 L150,183 L150,159 Z"
   id="Rectangle-Copy-19" fill="#30D1FF" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
    
    
    
    
   <path d="M150.5,68.5 L150.5,190" id="Line-3-Copy" stroke="#191919" stroke-linecap="square" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
   <text id="350%" font-size="12" font-weight="bold" line-spacing="16" fill="#FFFFFF">
   <tspan x="159" y="90">350%</tspan>
   </text>
   <text id="250%" font-size="12" font-weight="bold" line-spacing="16" fill="#FFFFFF">
    <tspan x="159" y="132">250%</tspan>
   </text>
   <text id="70%" font-size="12" font-weight="bold" line-spacing="16" fill="#FFFFFF">
   <tspan x="159" y="174">70%</tspan>
   </text>
</g>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```